# Working code in IntelliJ suddenly stopped while running cucumber tests due to this execption "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng, appium

**Issue Description:**
My code was running fine but suddenly it stopped working while invoking my cucumber appium tests due to below mentioned 2 exceptions, see text in bold from below:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=52980:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/testng/lib/testng-rt.jar:/Users/B/Desktop/XYZ/Automation/automation_merchantapp/target/test-classes:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.9.3/junit-jupiter-api-5.9.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.9.3/junit-platform-commons-1.9.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/appium/java-client/8.4.0/java-client-8.4.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/4.9.1/selenium-api-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.9.1/selenium-remote-driver-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/service/auto-service-annotations/1.0.1/auto-service-annotations-1.0.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/service/auto-service/1.0.1/auto-service-1.0.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/auto/auto-common/1.2/auto-common-1.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/31.1-jre/guava-31.1-jre.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/failureaccess/1.0.1/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/listenablefuture/9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava/listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.12.0/checker-qual-3.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.11.0/error_prone_annotations-2.11.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.3/j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.91.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.91.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.91.Final/netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.91.Final/netty-handler-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.91.Final/netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-classes-epoll/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-classes-kqueue/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.91.Final/netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.91.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.91.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api/1.25.0/opentelemetry-api-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-context/1.25.0/opentelemetry-context-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-exporter-logging/1.25.0/opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-metrics/1.25.0/opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-logs/1.25.0-alpha/opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.25.0-alpha.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api-logs/1.25.0-alpha/opentelemetry-api-logs-1.25.0-alpha.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-api-events/1.25.0-alpha/opentelemetry-api-events-1.25.0-alpha.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-common/1.25.0/opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi/1.25.0/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure/1.25.0-alpha/opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.25.0-alpha.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk-trace/1.25.0/opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-sdk/1.25.0/opentelemetry-sdk-1.25.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-semconv/1.25.0-alpha/opentelemetry-semconv-1.25.0-alpha.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/ous/jtoml/2.0.0/jtoml-2.0.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.14.4/byte-buddy-1.14.4.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.12.3/async-http-client-2.12.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/asynchttpclient/async-http-client-netty-utils/2.12.3/async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.60.Final/netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.60.Final/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.60.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.60.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/netty/netty-reactive-streams/2.0.4/netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-http/4.9.1/selenium-http-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/dev/failsafe/failsafe/3.3.1/failsafe-3.3.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-json/4.9.1/selenium-json-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-manager/4.9.1/selenium-manager-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/4.9.1/selenium-support-4.9.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/3.3.0/cglib-3.3.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.1/asm-7.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.7/commons-validator-1.7.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.10.1/gson-2.10.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-java/7.12.0/cucumber-java-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-core/7.12.0/cucumber-core-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin/7.12.0/cucumber-gherkin-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-gherkin-messages/7.12.0/cucumber-gherkin-messages-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/gherkin/26.2.0/gherkin-26.2.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/messages/22.0.0/messages-22.0.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/tag-expressions/5.0.1/tag-expressions-5.0.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/16.1.2/cucumber-expressions-16.1.2.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/datatable/7.12.0/datatable-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-plugin/7.12.0/cucumber-plugin-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/docstring/7.12.0/docstring-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/html-formatter/20.3.0/html-formatter-20.3.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/junit-xml-formatter/0.2.0/junit-xml-formatter-0.2.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/ci-environment/9.2.0/ci-environment-9.2.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-testng/7.12.0/cucumber-testng-7.12.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/7.7.1/testng-7.7.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.82/jcommander-1.82.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/3.6.1/jquery-3.6.1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.3.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.3.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.1.0/file-management-3.1.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/3.6.0/maven-archiver-3.6.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/3.4.0/plexus-io-3.4.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/4.4.0/plexus-archiver-4.4.0.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.21/commons-compress-1.21.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.4/snappy-0.4.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.9/xz-1.9.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.26/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar:/Users/B/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.4.2/plexus-utils-3.4.2.jar com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket52979 @w@/private/var/folders/gs/59wlpcwd3w956_rgvdvkw22r0000gp/T/idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp /private/var/folders/gs/59wlpcwd3w956_rgvdvkw22r0000gp/T/idea_testng.tmp
> SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
> Before Driver
> Starting
> **Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
> Host info: host: 'APB-LTB-MAC', ip: '2401:4900:55ce:8dad:d4a9:8818:2d5:f2d2%en0'**
>
> @manish
> Scenario: Verify merchant login with valid mobile number # src/test/resources/features/login.feature:7
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/B/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/3.3.0/cglib-3.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> When user clicks on SignIn                             # steps.LoginTestSteps.clickOnSignIn()
> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set**
> at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:59)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:97)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:77)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:46)
> at screens.LoginScreen.clickOnSignIn(LoginScreen.java:85)
> at steps.LoginTestSteps.clickOnSignIn(LoginTestSteps.java:37)
> at ✽.user clicks on SignIn(file:///Users/B/Desktop/XYZ/Automation/automation_merchantapp/src/test/resources/features/login.feature:8)
>
> And user enters the mobile number                      # steps.LoginTestSteps.user_enters_the_mobile_number()
> And user clicks on Send Otp                            # steps.LoginTestSteps.user_clicks_on_Send_Otp()
> And user enters the otp                                # steps.LoginTestSteps.user_enters_the_otp()
> And user clicks on sign in                             # steps.LoginTestSteps.user_clicks_on_sign_in()
> Then user should land on the home Screen               # steps.LoginTestSteps.user_should_land_on_the_home_Screen()
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input must be set
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require.nonNull(Require.java:59)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:97)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:77)
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:46)
> at screens.LoginScreen.clickOnSignIn(LoginScreen.java:85)
> at steps.LoginTestSteps.clickOnSignIn(LoginTestSteps.java:37)

**WHAT I TRIED**
I cross check same by going back to my previous stable commit which proves that its not my changes but it could probably with some IntelliJ IDE settings or some local system settings but as far as I remember I didn't change that either

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine after changing URL from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1!
Probably using tabnine was the cause for same not very sure though

Comment: You cannot refer to a service using `0.0.0.0`. If you see a message like `service is started at 0.0.0.0` that only means that it is bound to all network interfaces of the host. So you can use ip of any of them to access a service